# Managing Audio Volumes Separately for Background/Karaoke and Lyrics/Main in a Single Video using Exo Player

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm working on a project where I need to handle audio volumes separately for the background/karaoke and the lyrics/main in a single video. Is it possible to achieve this, and if so, what would be the best approach to manage multiple volume handlers for different components of the audio?
I'm particularly interested in solutions that are Android-specific. Any guidance, code snippets, or libraries that can help me achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!